# Error `The code you are testing needs to make 1 more call(s)` in testify package

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I am using the testify package for the unit testing in golang. My code contains mocking. while running the test it is getting passed for sometimes and showing error `The code you are testing needs to make 1 more call(s)` for sometimes, I am unable to figure out the reason why is this happening:

[image]

I went through this https://github.com/stretchr/testify/issues/31 but did get what is the problem and how it can be solved?

Comment: please provide a minimum "non"-working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read about the goroutine scheduling and come to know that if you are writing the test for the go functions(goroutines) then sometimes they may be called (the case when the test will pass and) and sometimes they may not be called.(the case when the test will fail). To recover from this one should use Gosched() in the test file where we are calling the goroutine. 
This happens because go uses cooperative scheduling for the scheduling for the goroutines, which is different from preemptive and non-preemptive. If anyone wants to more about it follow this. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11462

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was a silly mistake -

This could happen when you are unnecessarily mocking a method call and not actually calling the mocked method while performing your testing lifecycle.

Try removing the unnecessary method mocks you might have written, that might solve your problem!!

Answer (score -1):

If you used Code generated by mockery for create mock object. You will have method `NewYouInterface` in directory generate. When you use this method from for create your object you must use all you `mockObj.On("method",..).Reutrn()`, because after finished your test run "`func t.Cleanup(func() { mock.AssertExpectations(t) })`
. But you can create without follower code `new(repoMock.RepoEntity)`, this is will help you)